# Unable to assign value to an ActiveModel attribute (rails 4.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have created a simple users model in rails 4.2. However I am unable to assign any attribute values in the rails console

```
2.1.5 :001 > u = User.new
=> #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, auth_token: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, enabled: true>
2.1.5 :002 > u.name = 'sample'
=> "sample"
2.1.5 :003 > u.changed
=> []
2.1.5 :004 > u
=> #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, auth_token: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, enabled: true>
```

As you can see despite setting name the value has not changed.

Here is the model file

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :id

  include Tokenable
  include Creatable
  include Updatable

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :auth_token, :created_at, :updated_at, :enabled
end
```

I know that this works fine in rails 3.2

Comment: Remove `attr_accessor`. It is not needed. Also remove `self.primary_key = :id`, `:id` is default no need to tell it.

Comment: also  remove  `self.primary_key = :id` since Active Record will use an integer column named id as the table's primary key. When using Active Record Migrations to create your tables, this column will be automatically created.

Comment: @JohnBaker actually migrations don't really matter. AR does not read `schema.rb` - it reads the database table metadata from the DB and generates setters/getters. Thats why you can't load a model without a database connection.

Comment: @max agree, just meant to point that you don't have to specify :id as primary key in your model, since in Rails that is always set to be so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the biggest "selling points" of ActiveRecord is that it automatically creates setters and getters in your models based on the DB schema.

These are not just your average accessors created by `attr_accessor` (which is plain Ruby), they cast values to the correct type and do dirty tracking among other things.

When you use `attr_accessor` you´re generating setters and getters that clobber those created by ActiveRecord - which means that AR will not track changes or persist the attributes.

This is what you really want:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tokenable
  include Creatable
  include Updatable
end
```

Only use `attr_accessor` in models when you need setters and getters for non-persisted ("virtual") attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the record after assigning the new value. You can achieve that by calling `update_attribute!` or `save!` on your object. In your case:

```
u.name = "sample"
u.save!
```

or

```
u.update_attribute("name", "sample")
```

Note that `update_attribute` updates a single attribute and saves the record without going through the normal validation procedure

Comment: Nope this doesnt work. It gives an sql error because the insert statement doesnt have the name `INSERT INTO 'users' ('created_at', 'updated_at') VALUES ('2018-08-17 13:36:05.459761', '2018-08-17 13:36:05.459761')`

Comment: The state tracking and persistence won't work properly anyways due to the use of `attr_accessor`

Comment: And you may want to read the docs for [ActiveModel::Dirty](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) - it tracks changes to attributes even without saving the model.

Comment: @JCDenton yes, I assumed that you did remove `attr_accessor`